# How to parsing JSON file(Array) in Qt5 (C++), using QJsonArray

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5

I am tring Qt5. I try to read values from a json file. Json file is like the one above:

**test.json**

```
[{"w":188,"h":334,"th":0.350000,"l":232,"r":420,"t":133,"b":467,"p":0.713963,"n":"person"}]
[{"w":127,"h":141,"th":0.350000,"l":1152,"r":1279,"t":162,"b":303,"p":0.408129,"n":"person"},{"w":179,"h":339,"th":0.350000,"l":230,"r":409,"t":131,"b":470,"p":0.698172,"n":"person"}]
```

It's under code I try. How to read such a json file structure ?

```
QString val;
QFile file;
file.setFileName("test.json");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
//file is readall
val = file.readAll();
file.close();
qWarning() << val; //print consol
QJsonDocument jsonDocument = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
//get data array !!!
QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonDocument.object();
QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["w"].toArray();
qWarning() << jsonArray[0].toString();
```

Comment: What is the actual question? What doesn't work as you would expect and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt parsing JSON using QJsonDocument, QJsonObject, QJsonArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822211/qt-parsing-json-using-qjsondocument-qjsonobject-qjsonarray)

Comment: This text does not respect the json format. `[values1] [values2]`  not json

Comment: You can verify if it is an appropriate json format in the following link: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Okey. My my json file format, every line [blank] or [object {1}] or [{1} object, the object {2} ....] can form. I am trying to read this format. But I could not read it properly in this format Qt5. How to read in this format.

Comment: I made the correction above. The json file looks like this.

Comment: @O.OZTURK see my answer

Comment: @O.OZTURK Your text is invalid JSON. It should be { "someKey": [your 1st array], '"someOtherKey" : [your 2nd array] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data does not have a JSON format (it is ill-formed, see [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)), but if it is in parts, what we must do is to separate it, for that we use `QRegularExpresion`, and we verify that the data has an appropriate format, then the code is similar to your code.

**Code:**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile file("test.json");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qWarning() << "Could not open file!";
        return 0;
    }
    const auto& data = QString(file.readAll());
    file.close();

    QRegularExpression regex("\\[|\\]");
    const auto& jsons = data.split(regex);

    for(const auto& json : jsons)
        if(!json.trimmed().isEmpty()){
            const auto& formattedJson = QString("[%1]").arg(json);
            const auto& doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(formattedJson.toUtf8());

            if(doc.isArray())
                for(const auto& item : doc.array()){
                    const auto& obj = item.toObject();
                    const auto& keys = obj.keys();

                    for(const auto& key : keys){
                        if(key == "n")
                            qDebug() << key << obj[key].toString();
                        else
                            qDebug() << key << obj[key].toInt();
                    }
                }
        }

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Output:**

```
"b" 467
"h" 334
"l" 232
"n" "person"
"p" 0
"r" 420
"t" 133
"th" 0
"w" 188
"b" 303
"h" 141
"l" 1152
"n" "person"
"p" 0
"r" 1279
"t" 162
"th" 0
"w" 127
"b" 470
"h" 339
"l" 230
"n" "person"
"p" 0
"r" 409
"t" 131
"th" 0
"w" 179
```

Comment: Why not `split` at `'\n'` instead of using regular expression?

Comment: @Azeem I'm assuming the most general case, I also thought of applying the same thing but the data may be in a single line, my solution covers both cases.

Comment: @Azeem It's always good to think about the worst case, the only one I can be sure of is that the date will be between `[]`.

Comment: @eyllanesec: I got your point and for the given ill-formed JSON format it seems okay.

Comment: Thank you for anwer. I guess it's gonna work. @eyllanesec