# C++ parse text from .txt file to variables

Tags: c++, linux, qt, parsing, qt-creator

what is the simplest way to parse data(C++) from my text file and store it to variables?
I have a parse_data.txt with this text:

```
{"song":"Holiday","artist":"Green Day","Album":"American Idiot","Service":"Spotify"}
```

I need store Holiday to song variable, Green Day to artist variable...

so QString song = Holiday...

Can someone show me some examples?

Comment: The data looks to be in `json` format. You can use https://nlohmann.github.io/json/ to parse json content and do your tasks.

Comment: This looks like JSON. Nobody will be able to show you "some examples", because this is simply done by using any one of several publicly available JSON parsers. Nobody does this manually, by themselves. Unfortunately, asking for software recommendations is off-topic for stackoverflow.com

Comment: Qt has JSON support. [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html)

Comment: Check this link: http://erickveil.github.io/2016/04/06/How-To-Manipulate-JSON-With-C++-and-Qt.html

Comment: Also, there is a [game tutorial (by Qt)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-serialization-savegame-example.html)! You should definitely check out the files to see how they handle JSON formatted files, if you happen to be using the file for multiple objects (in serialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we assume that you are using QT? If so, there is an response here that can show you an example on how to use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822211/qt-parsing-json-using-qjsondocument-qjsonobject-qjsonarray)

Here is how you can apply to your code

```
QString jsonString = [your json string represenation];
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonString.toUtf8());
QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();
QJsonValue jsonValue = jsonObject["song"];
QString strValue = jsonValue.toString();
```